# How to place the text in desired position of a new page in pdf?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

I am using CSharp and iTextSharp for creating pdf.

This is my code to place the text:

```
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
        cb.BeginText();
        cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, text, width, height, 0);
        cb.EndText();
```

After I create new page using.

```
        doc.NewPage();
```

and try to place the text in new page like this is not working:

```
        cb.BeginText();
        cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, text, width, height, 0);
        cb.EndText();
```

But This is working:

```
        ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(cb, Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
        new Phrase(Petrol[i], font), 451 + i * x, 684, 0)
```

Can someone explain why cb.ShowTextAligned() is not worked.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/958478/1358004

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. This question is about creating a document from scratch, not about replacing text in an existing document. However: Giri may deserve a vote down because of two questions in this category: http://lowagie.com/node/410

Comment: Sorry,Can you tell me the question which is in same category?